# Why the calculation of a probability distribution mean works

Tags: probability, random-variable

We know that the mean of a random variable is calculated by adding up the multiplication of the random variable values with their related (probability distribution) probabilities.

But what I am trying to get my head round is how this is actually working without dividing by the number of values in the random variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ denote a discrete random variable that takes on values
$\{u_1, u_2, \ldots, u_n\}$, and suppose that $N$ repeated independent
trials of the experiment are performed.  If $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_N$ are the
observed values of $X$ on these $N$ trials, then the *average
observed value* of $X$ in these trials is
$$\frac{x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_N}{N}.$$
But each $x_i \in \{u_1, u_2, \ldots, u_n\}$ and so instead of adding $N$
numbers to compute the sum in the numerator above, we can count the
number of times that $u_j$ occurs in the sum, say $M_j$ times, and rewrite
the average as
\begin{align}\frac{x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_N}{N} &=
\frac{M_1u_1 + M_2u_2 + \cdots + M_nu_n}{N}\\
&=  \frac{M_1}{N}\cdot u_1
+ \frac{M_2}{N}\cdot u_2  + \cdots + \frac{M_n}{N}\cdot u_n.
\end{align}
Note that $M_1 + M_2 + \cdots + M_n = N$.  Now, $\dfrac{M_j}{N}$ is the
*observed relative frequency* of the event $\{X = u_j\}$,
and if $N$ is *large*, then we *expect* that this relative frequency $\dfrac{M_j}{N}$
is *approximately* $P\{X = u_j\} = p_{X}(u_j)$.  Thus,
the average observed value of $X$ on a large number of repeated
independent trials is *expected* to be
$$\frac{x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_N}{N} \approx u_1\cdot p_{X}(u_1) + u_2\cdot p_{X}(u_2) + \cdots + u_n\cdot p_{X}(u_n).$$
This approximation motivates the definition of the *expected value*
or *expectation* or *average* or *mean* of a discrete random variable as being given by
$$E[X] = \sum_i u_i\cdot p_X(u_i).$$
Note that there is no division by $n$ -- the number of *values* taken on by the discrete random variable -- but there *is* implicitly a division by $N$ -- the total number of *trials* -- in how we arrived at the formula for $E[X]$.

Comment: I removed the `\rv` part for I couldn't get what was tried to be rendered at.

Answer (score 1):

A weighted mean is computed by multiplying each value by a weight, then dividing by the sum of the weights.  The mean of a probability distribution follows this idea: you multiply each $x$ value by its probability (the weight) and in the case of a proper probability distribution the sum of the probabilities is 1, so you could finish by dividing by 1 (the sum of the weights), but we usually leave that step out since it does not change the value at all.

In the case of a discrete uniform distribution, then the probability/weight/height is just $\frac1n$ for each $x$ value (with $n$ distinct values), so at each step you would multiply by $\frac1n$ which is equivalent to adding the values up then dividing by $n$.